# web service basic

Tags: java, service

actually may be this is not the right place to ask. but  i think i will get more help from this site regarding this matter than googling. i have some ideas about web service. but i am not clear actually what it does. can i get link of some good books/tutorials where i can learn web service and its implementation. i will prefer if it is in java.

can i get some ideas about a web service based project. actually i don't know what is the application of web service. plz help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaEE, you can write a web service with code as simple as:

```
@WebService
public class TestWS
{
    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Deploy this class to a JavaEE application server (i.e. JBoss), and you'll have your first WebService online.

[Here's a quick tutorial](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/threeminutes.html) to Java WebServices.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/default.asp